# Ubuntu logo into Unicode table

Tags: special-characters, unicode, logo

I was searching something into [an Unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html). Suddenly, I feel astonished cause I saw the Ubuntu logo, at line F200, column 00. A very small one is also available at F0E0, column 1F.

Is it because *this* table on *this* web page has been generated with a Ubuntu system or something? Or can I find it on any OS???

What can be the reason to put this logo into the *special-characters* of Unicode set?

Comment: I came here looking for a larger ubuntu circle logo. Found it at `E0FF`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid not. U+F200 is in the [Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29) ([E000—F8FF range](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/private-use-area/)). These are not official Unicode characters.

Comment: And also, only the Ubuntu font family makes this character position be the Ubuntu logo.

Comment: As a matter of policy, Unicode does not encode logos as characters. This is expressed in Ch. 1 of the standard, http://www.unicode.org/latest/Unicode6.1.0/ch01.pdf near end of page 2. (Anything in a Private Use Area is up to agreements between interested parties, and should not be expected to work in any context outside such agreements.)

Answer (score 5):

Since I came across the same question as the OP and things have changed since the accepted answer was posted, I thought I'd share my findings:

Both Ubuntu logos (shown correctly below, if font is installed) are in fact "normal" characters now. They can be typed just like <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>, too. You just need to type the Unicode sequence for them.

In order to achieve this, you just have to install the [Ubuntu Font](http://font.ubuntu.com/) (download button right below the test area) and you're good to go!

Lastly, the OP made two little mistakes: he mixed up 0 with O and column with row. Hence, the correct locations are line F200, **column 00** () and line F**0**E**0**, **column** 1F ().