# Byobu weird character

Tags: byobu, unicode

After the last byobu's update, I realized that the weird character in bottom left of terminal was not repaired. This character is right or not? See link below.

[image]

Ubuntu 14.04; Language: **English (US)**; Regional Formats: **pt_BR**

Comment: What do you mean by "not repaired"? There should be the CoF next to the `u` at least if you use Ubuntu Mono as the font.

Comment: I discovered it myself before reading your answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That *weird* character, sometimes displayed as ⌷, is the [Ubuntu unicode logo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144379/ubuntu-logo-into-unicode-table), .

Byobu tries to use Unicode symbols, but sometimes those may not display correctly, if you're on a system that doesn't include that character in its font set.  All of Byobu's symbols are tested to display properly on on Ubuntu (with the [Ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/)) within Gnome-Terminal, but your mileage may vary on other terminals (such as Putty), other Linux systems, Windows or MacOS.

You can disable the logo entirely, by going to the [Byobu](http://byobu.co) configuration menu, by either pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> or running `byobu-config`, selecting, "Toggle Status Notifications", de-selecting "logo", and then pressing "Apply".

And you can toggle all [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) characters on/off by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>, or running `/usr/lib/byobu/include/toggle-utf8`.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Hmm, I am on Ubuntu and I was using terminator as terminal. I just discovered that terminator use monospaced font instead of ubuntu mono. This why this character has never appeared to me. Thanks!!

Comment: That's a nice answer. Could you possibly expand on why I can only see ⌷ within a Putty session on Windows that uses Ubuntu Mono and displays the CoF as in your answer, but only ⌷ where ▴▾ (network activity), ⟳ (reboot required) and ⟫ (prompt) should be? Or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Sure thing!  Done.

Comment: @Dustin Do you know why I still have one ⌷? I use Ubuntu mono and UTF-8 in putty. I think it may be the "reboot required" icon.
https://i.imgur.com/7MHykKZ.png