# The 'reboot required' character doesn't render with PuTTY and Ubuntu Mono

Tags: fonts, byobu, putty, ubuntu-font-family

I have "Remote character set" to "UTF-8" and the font set to "Ubuntu Mono, 12-point".

The Ubuntu logo character render correctly but not the "reboot required" character.

Is there a way to fix this?

I'm using PuTTY on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: For a related question, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/492802/ .

Comment: Yes. I asked my question as  a comment on the related question.