# How can I override Byobu's distro logo not using statusrc config?

Tags: 16.04, byobu

I can't override the default logo for the actual distro. I followed the [man page instructions](http://manpg.es/tmux.1) but it didn't change at all. It's still looking like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492802/byobu-weird-character).

Am I missing something?

I'm using Byobu 5.106 (with tmux: 2.1) and fish shell 2.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set text for the log at `~/.byobu/statusrc` or `/usr/share/byobu/status/statusrc`

The latter will be used as defaults for all users.

I could change the default logo into `"U "` by this.

```
# Default: depends on the distro (which is either auto-detected, either set
# via $DISTRO)
#LOGO="\o/"
LOGO="U "
```

Setting `""` does not work but `" "` can be used, instead.

Comment: So there's no other way than setting it into `statusrc`... I don't know what happened to my byobu but I tried that with no luck. Anyway, since this is the correct answer and solves it in most cases, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Does not help me either :<
I'm on Ubuntu Server 20...